# jQuery selectors: logical OR

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I can't seem to see the forest for the trees right now (Looked at the api docs already).
It has to do with jQuery selectors: What I'm trying to do is to select all elements that have class `subtitle` or `headsection`. Something like this: `$('.headsection || .subtitle');`

To be more specific: I want to use this selector with the function `nextUntil`.

```
$content = $some_elements.eq(0).nextUntil('.headsection || subtitle');
```

As far as I know `||` is not available in jQuery's selectors. So what's the best way to accomplish that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What about: `$some_elements.eq(0).nextUntil('.headsection, .subtitle');`

Works for me at least. Read about [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Comment: OMG yes, that works. As I looked through the docs I thought the comma would work like an AND. Thanks @all

Comment: @RamboNo5 I was thinking of exactly the same logic thinking of adding || but thinking about it, how css works, why on earth did I not initially think comma haha

Answer (score 58):

It's the same as in CSS selectors:

```
$('.headsection, .subtitle');
```

Answer (score 5):

Just separate them with a comma:

```
$content = $some_elements.eq(0).nextUntil('.headsection, subtitle');
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need a logical OR as such, `$('.headsection, .subtitle')` should do the job.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery uses the CSS selector syntax, so if you know that, just put the same selectors into jQuery and bob's your metaphorical uncle. jQuery uses the [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) selector engine which supports  virtually all CSS3 selectors :)

As everyone has already said - the way to do it is this: `$content = $some_elements.eq(0).nextUntil('.headsection, subtitle');`

Answer (score 3):

Would the multiple selector work for what you're doing?
[Api doc is here.](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)