# jquery find logical operator inside selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I search ([jquery find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)) elements without using comma seperator. [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3p3EG/).

Example:

```
<div id="inputs">
    <input name="n1" value="v1" type="text" />
    <input name="n2" value="v2" type="checkbox" />
    <input name="n3" value="v3" type="button" />
    <input name="n4" value="v4" type="hidden" />
    <input name="n5" value="v5" type="text" />
    <input name="n6" value="v6" type="text" />
    <input name="n7" value="v7" type="text" />
    <input name="n8" value="v8" type="text" />
    <input name="n9" value="v9" type="text" />
    <input name="n10" value="v10" type="text" />
</div>
```

1- I can do this with following code:

```
$('#inputs')
    .find('input[type="text"][name="n7"], input[type="text"][name="n8"]')
    .val("found");
```

2- But how I want to use this is like:

```
$('#inputs')
    .find('input[type="text"][name="n7" || "n8"])
    .val("found");
```

Reason: Just curious and think there might be a performance difference (second is faster).

Comment: What about `$('#inputs input:text').filter('[name="n7"], [name="n8"]')`?

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396596/jquery-selectors-logical-or), it's not possible to do it without using a comma

Comment: @Bergi thank you for fast response, it is working well, but not an answer.

Comment: You can set up a http://jsperf.com/ and compare the first way to something similar to the second one, e.g. with `.filter`. As you already know (I hope), `[name="n7" || "n8"]` does not exist, so it doesn't make sense to speculate about which one would be faster.

Comment: Also @tpbowden thank you actually I couldn't find it. So i get my answer. Sorry for disturbance. Hope google searchers find the right link from here.

Comment: I can't really see why there would be a performance increase with a regex instead of looking up the names twice, in fact I would thinking using the comma would be faster, and doing `document.getElementsByName('n7')[0].value = 'found';` twice (for `n8`) would certainly be faster.

Comment: @FelixKling I am not a javascript guy really, but when I think the comma seperated version it looks like (logically) searching in the same bigger $('#inputs') selector two times for the first part input[type="text"], isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I search elements without using comma seperator.

You cannot, the comma between multiple selectors is the only OR-operator available.

However, you can chain the searches and use the comma operator on a single level only:

```
$('#inputs input[type="text"]').filter('[name="n7"], [name="n8"]')
```

This is indeed more concise (no repetition) and should be more efficient as well. If you really want to match multiple values against a single attribute expression, use a custom filter function:

```
$('#inputs input:text').filter(function() {
    var name = this.name;
    return name=="n7" || name=="n8"; // or
    return ~["n7","n8"].indexOf(this.name); // or
    return /^n[78]$/.test(this.name); // or whatever
});
```

Comment: +1 for a nice solution using the `||` syntax, though I would be very surprised if a developer would use a convoluted filter option simply to avoid the comma separation syntax (Assuming the custom filter function offers no added benefit).

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: Sure, this example is too trivial. I just wanted to point at filter predicates for cases where javascript operators, nested expression or complicated logic is required.