# Select all elements that have one class and also either of two other classes?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I had a working selector that I'm using to enhance a website with Tampermonkey.

I identified that the elements I wanted to work with all had both a `title` class and an `unread` class. I selected them this way.

```
var sel = document.querySelectorAll('.title.unread');
for (var i = 0, e; e = sel[i]; i++) {
  e.title = e.innerText;
}
```

Now I've found that I also want the elements that have both a `title` class and a `read` class.

So logically I want a selector that does the job of the pseduocode `.title + (.read OR .unread)`

What's the most elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: This might be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396596/jquery-selectors-logical-or

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking at?

```
var sel = document.querySelectorAll('.title.unread, .title.read');
```

Comment: Yes! Moments after posting the question and before getting your answer I discovered the same solution and was just about to post it.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

```js
var sel = document.querySelectorAll('.title.unread, .title.read');
console.log(sel);
```

```html
<div class="title unread"></div>
<div class="title"></div>
<div class="title read"></div>
```

### The mathematics

While there is no parenthesis between CSS selectors but there is:

- an OR: the comma: `,`
- an AND: writing next to each other: `.a.b`

So according to [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) and the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property), your expression can be expanded:

`.title AND (.read OR .unread) == (.title AND .read) OR (.title AND .unread)`

Answer (score 1):

You separate CSS selectors by using **comma**.In this case, you want to separate them like following:

```
var sel = document.querySelectorAll('.title.read, .title.unread');
```

In case you want to expand knowledge of **css selectors**, you can visit [w3schools CSS Selectors Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).Here, you can find examples of how each selector should be used.